# GET and POST methods and how they should be used

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, post, flask

I am building a locally hosted website via flask that I will use to scrape sites like craigslist. I have run into some problems getting the main index page to update correctly. I am a novice when it comes to this sort of fullstack level development.

Why is the front page of my website not updating when I change the variable being passed into the javascript? Whenever I POST(i.e. make a submission via a search box, the Entries variable doesn't appear to update. I am very new to javascript so please be gentle. ;)

below is the code:

```
<head>
    <title>Flask app</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/main.css') }}">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

  </head>
<body>

  <div class="topnav">
    <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
    <a href="#about">About</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    <form class = "form" action="/index" method="POST">
      <input id ="textbox" name="textbox" type="text" placeholder="Search..">
      <button type="submit">submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>

  <p id="search-query"> you searched: </p>

  <div id="div1">
  <p id="p1"></p>
  <p id="p2"></p>
  </div>





<script>

var value = $('.textbox').val();
//alert(value);
$("button").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var value = $("#textbox").val();
    //alert(value);
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: "index",
      data: JSON.stringify({"text" : value}),
      contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
      success: function(data){
        $("#search-query").text("you search: " + data["text"]);
        //alert(JSON.stringify(data));
      }
    });
});

var jsonz = {{ entries|tojson }};
var s = JSON.parse(jsonz);

var i;
for (i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
  var para = document.createElement("p");
  var node = document.createTextNode(s[i].product_name + "\n" + s[i].product_link);
  para.appendChild(node);

  var element = document.getElementById("div1");
  element.appendChild(para);
}


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is app.py

```
from scraper import scrape
from flask import Flask, render_template, jsonify, make_response, request
import json
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        search = request.get_json()

        search = json.dumps(search)
        search = json.loads(search)
        search = search['text']
        print search
        #search = json.loads(search)
        entries = json.dumps(scrape(search))
        return render_template('index.html', entries = entries)

    elif request.method == "GET":


        entries = json.dumps(scrape("cars"))
        return render_template('index.html', entries= entries)
    else:
        return render_template('index.html')



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

Comment: From where `entries` came into picture in Javascript file?

Comment: var jsonz = {{ entries|tojson }};
var s = JSON.parse(jsonz);
   this is where i pass it in

Comment: Yeah that's fine, I am asking, where you declared `entries` in the javascript file?

Comment: I guess i forgot to declare it. I am confused by passing something in to the front end and having to declare it. Could you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can make a check below these steps

1、check your ajax url is define in your flask app, your flask app do not define '/index', so please check your api is work correctly, like this

```
@app.route("/index", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
```

2、ajax receive data but not html page, so your flask should return data(i.e,`{text:"xxxx"}`),then you can use `$("#search-query").text("you search: " + data["text"]);` to update, like this

```
@app.route("/index", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
if request.method == 'POST':
    search = request.get_json()

    search = json.dumps(search)
    search = json.loads(search)
    search = search['text']
    print search
    #search = json.loads(search)
    entries = json.dumps(scrape(search))
    return entries
```

hope it can help you!

Comment: I understand now that there is javascript in my index.html that is not updating. How can i get it to update?

Comment: you can see the code in my answer,you api do not return html page,it should return data you need